# How to Update RecyclerView Contents without UI lag While scrolling?

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview

I have 5000 items in RecyclerView and i want to sort by Ascending order and descending order of the items, Once i sorted items i'm trying to update recyclerView items by calling notifyDataSetChanged()

meanwhile if we are scrolling recyclerView contents app is getting hang for a second how to update recyclerView items without UI lag?

Comment: Please show me your adapter code!

Comment: Multithreading is the solution for your problem!

Comment: Use pagination and load item 10/20/50 per page

Comment: You can easily fix the lag without pagination it's really not needed @Quicklearner

Comment: Use DiffUtil in RecycleView https://medium.com/@iammert/using-diffutil-in-android-recyclerview-bdca8e4fbb00